# Scroll view with Relative layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button

I am building a layout with scroll view and inside the scroll view, there is a relative layout. I want to place the `FloatingActionButton` on the bottom center of the layout, but I don't know what is happening.

This is my layout:

[image]

Here's my code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mani.fakecall.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/display_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_image_button"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/display_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/enter_number"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/display_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/enter_name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:text="@string/set_time" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_call_white_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFab"
            app:elevation="0dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy will be like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mani.fakecall.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/display_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_image_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/display_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/enter_number"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/display_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/enter_name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="@string/set_time" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:elevation="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

edited

Comment: I tried your way but now the `FloatingActionButton` is unnecessarily moving.

Comment: Make sure, Your parent is RelativeLayout, not Scrollview

Comment: You can copy and paste my code above in the question and then you can edit it in your way like you said and then run the app on your device.

Comment: Yes, the parent is `RelativeLayout`

Comment: height of `LinearLayout` should `wrap_content`